# How can I show Product Backlog Items on TFS board grouped by people?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

In TFS 2015 we are using the Scrum process template.  When I 'group by people' only the tasks are showing up on the board, but not the PBI's (product backlog items) or bugs.

How can I get the PBI's and Bugs that are assigned to my team to show up when I group the backlog by people?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't see User Story if you use "Group by: People".

But you can see bugs, you need to configure it according the picture:

[image]

**Another option:** you can install [Query based boards](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=realdolmen.querybasedboards) extension, This extension allows you to visualize the result of work item queries on a board. The order by clauses of the query are respected on the board.

After installing the extension, navigate to the Work hub, and select Queries. When opening a query, a new tab called Board is available to visualize the results on a board.

Answer (score 0):

Bugs could be added **by default**, the detail steps please follow the
   official tutorial-- [Show bugs on backlogs and boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/show-bugs-on-backlog?view=vsts)

However, for PBIs, you need to do it by **customizing your process**
   or team project, based on the process model you use. For details,
   please refer this link: [Add other work item types to your backlogs
   or boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/show-bugs-on-backlog?view=vsts#add-other-work-item-types-to-your-backlogs-or-boards)